# KeyListener not working the way I want it to for arrow keys?

Tags: java, keylistener, arrow-keys

I am making a the snake game and I have implemented the KeyListener class that listens to when the user presses the arrow keys or WASD keys.

In snake, when you press a movement key, the snake will continue to move if you just press a movement key once, and will only go in another direction once you enter a different movement command. However, in my program I have to hold the key down for the snake to move, I can't just press it once. How do I make it so that I just have to press the key once to move the snake?

Also, the WASD keys are working differently than the arrow keys. When I press a WASD key, the snake only moves one block and then stops, unlike the arrow keys where the snake moves as long as I hold down the arrow keys. How do I make the WASD keys work the same way as I want the arrow keys to work?

Here is the code:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        out.println("Left key pressed");
        // handle snake left movement
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        out.println("Right key pressed");
        // handle snake right movement
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        out.println("Up key pressed");
        // handle snake up movement
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        out.println("Down key pressed");
        // handle snake down movement
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}
```

Comment: Change your "handle snake movement" code to keep going, instead of only moving once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, thank you @azurefrog, @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, and @AJNeufeld. Here is my solution in case other people have the same problem as mine. Disclaimer: I am not done with this game so the "snake" is just a block, I still have to figure out how to make it an actual snake. I am just posting this to show how I handled the movement of the snake.

First, I made two global variables in my `Snake` class (the class of the game):

```
private String currentDir = "";
private Timer moveTimer = new Timer(100, new MoveListener());
```

Then, I made a `MoveListener` class that extends the `ActionListener` class. This `MoveListener` class serves as the parameter for the `moveTimer`:

```
private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        out.println("timer action called");
        int snakeX = 0;
        int snakeY = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < positions.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < positions[row].length; col++) {
                if (positions[row][col] == 's') {
                    snakeX = row;
                    snakeY = col;
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentDir.equals("left")) {
            positions[snakeX - 1][snakeY] = 's';
            positions[snakeX][snakeY] = '\u0000';
            repaint();
        } else if (currentDir.equals("right")) {
            positions[snakeX + 1][snakeY] = 's';
            positions[snakeX][snakeY] = '\u0000';
            repaint();
        } else if (currentDir.equals("up")) {
            positions[snakeX][snakeY - 1] = 's';
            positions[snakeX][snakeY] = '\u0000';
            repaint();
        } else if (currentDir.equals("down")) {
            positions[snakeX][snakeY + 1] = 's';
            positions[snakeX][snakeY] = '\u0000';
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I made my `KeyListener` so that it simply set the variable `currentDir` based on the corresponding movement keys, and started the `MoveTimer` thread.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        out.println("Left key pressed");
        currentDir = "left";
        moveTimer.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        out.println("Right key pressed");
        currentDir = "right";
        moveTimer.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        out.println("Up key pressed");
        currentDir = "up";
        moveTimer.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        out.println("Down key pressed");
        currentDir = "down";
        moveTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to turn your game's event loop into something driven by a `Timer`, which would consult a `current_direction` variable for your snake.  The `KeyListener` would set this `currect_direction` variable.

Using a `Timer` allows your game to be independent of the key repeat rate.  This allows you to increase/decrease the difficulty of your game.

Comment: Correct, specifically a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). (1+)

Comment: +1 That sounds like a good idea but I have already tried using Swing Timer, and while it did make the snake move slower, there were some weird bugs that I have no idea why they happened. :/

Comment: Did you ask a different question about those weird bugs you experienced using the Swing Timer, complete with a [mcve] that we can look at?

Comment: @parrot15: then debug your bugs, and look at examples of Swing animation with Swing Timer that you can find on this site, including [mine that uses both a Swing Timer and Key Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920732/522444).